# how to collect to LinkedHashMap in java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Currently we are converting list returned by `repository.findAll()` into the Map by doing:

```
Map<Long, FooDto> fooMap=fooRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(fooDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(fooDto::getfooId, foo -> foo));
```

But we want to preserve the order returned by the `repository.findAll()`. We want to return the records in the descending order and then collect it to the `LinkedHashmap` by doing something like :

```
Map<Long, FooDto> fooMap= fooRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"))
                .stream()
                .map(fooDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto)
                //trying to do something like:
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(fooDto::getfooId, foo -> foo,LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If we try to collect the above descending order result in the normal `Collectors.toMap` then sorted query has no effect at all, it is looking like normal select in the final result.

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#:~:text=toMap) and you’ll see that there is no three-arg version of `toMap` accepting a map supplier, only a four arg overload. So you have to insert a merge function before the map supplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass a supplier for the `Map`, you must pass a merge function too:

```
Map<Long, FooDto> fooRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"))
            .stream()
            .map(fooDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(fooDto::getfooId,
                                      Function.identity(),
                                      (v1,v2)->v1,
                                      LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: When you assume the keys to be unique, you should use `(v1,v2)->{ throw new AssertionError(); }` as merge function, instead of silently overwriting values if the assertion does not hold.

Comment: @Holger I'm not sure `AssertionError` is wise here. Usually it's indicative of a situation which logically should never happen, whereas this is an assertion on the input data, and cannot be logically ruled out. Errors are not caught by `catch(Exception e)`, and are generally treated as fatal, which again does not seem appropriate here. `(v1,v2)->{ throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected duplicate values:" + Arrays.asList(v1, v2)); }` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @MikeFHay this depends on whether the IDs of the repository count as input data. The result does not differ much. Both, `RuntimeException` and `Error`, are unchecked and usually not caught (and `catch(Exception e)` is considered code smell and flagged by almost every audit tool). Tools for asynchronous execution will catch all throwables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .stream()
 .map(fooDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto)
 .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, 
          (map, fooDto) -> map.put(fooDto.getfooId(), fooDto),
          Map::putAll);
```